# Studies involving the looks of software

Tags: user-interface

Have their been any studies related to the importance of how good a software looks in terms of perception or saleability?

I have a feeling this is much more important then people give it credit for, but I would really like to see some hard data to back it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keywords you are after is "Human-Computer-Interaction". There is loads of studies in that area, I even spent a full semester at uni on the subject, where it was spoken of as "HCI".

However, they do focus on the *usability* of a software program. The perception of a software program does impact the usability, however, under the theory that the more familiar a program is to the user, the less difficulty the user will have with using it.

The saleability, however...  I doubt that's even related to the software, let alone its user interface other than that it satisfies a checklist that the consumer may have.

Answer (score 1):

Donald Norman has done a bunch on this, going as far as stating that "Good looking things work better". I'm currently reading his book "Emotional Design" and I'm finding myself slowly persuaded, though on first face I disagreed vehemently.